# Word in SpaCy vocabulary but has no associated vector

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I trained a model on curated text, but when I cannot retrieve vectors for entities that the nlp recognizes and are in its vocabulary.

My understanding is that every word in a SpaCy vocabulary, whether a from a custom or pretrained model, is associated with a vector?

Example:

```
 sample_string = "DNP is a thing."
 for ent in doc.ents:
     print(f"Named Entity '{ent.text}' with label '{ent.label_}'") 
     #prints Named Entity 'DNP' with label 'SUBSTANCE'
 print(nlp("DNP").vector) -> # []
 print(nlp.vocab.strings["DNP"]) # -> 12623617258395969273
 print(nlp.vocab.vectors[nlp.vocab.strings["DNP"]]) # -> Could not retrieve vector for key 12623617258395969273.'
 print("DNP" in list(nlp.vocab.strings)) #-> True
```

Comment: Same question on spaCy forums. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/10931

Comment: Yes, I cross-posted on the chance my issues is judged more appropriate for that forum. Same question.